# Does exportUnderlyingDataEnabled override exportDataEnabled?

Tags: powerbi

PowerBI has many feature switches, including "exportUnderlyingDataEnabled" and "exportDataEnabled". What are the differences between the two feature switches? If they are set to different values, which one overrides which?